# React-Native: Logical comparison of WritableMap

Tags: java, react-native

I try to compare the result of an asynchronous function as below:

```
WritableMap res;
res = ServerAuthenticate.signIn(userName, userPass);

Log.d(TAG, " --> res.getString(status).length(): " + res.getString("status").length());
Log.d(TAG, " --> res.getString(status): " + res.getString("status"));
Log.d(TAG, " --> res.getString('status') == 'OK': " + (res.getString("status") == "OK"));
```

The code of above gives the following console outputs:

```
D/!NativeModules( 5899): --> res.getString(status).length(): 2
D/!NativeModules( 5899): --> res.getString(status): OK
D/!NativeModules( 5899): --> res.getString('status') == 'OK': false
```

`res.getString("status")` value is `OK` string but when I put it to a comparison as `res.getString("status") == "OK"` it returns `false`. Actually I use the method of `results.putString("status", "OK");` in `ServerAuthenticate.signIn()` function.

I wonder if is there any way to compare a property value of a `WritableMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard Java String equals problem. Try `res.getString("status").equals("OK")` or for better null safety `"OK".equals(res.getString("status"))`.

See also [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)